# Send parameters from jsp form to a java servlet in a different project

Tags: forms, web-services, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I want to be able to send form inputs from a jsp to a java servlet that's held in a different project in netbeans. I have had a look at many different tutorials and they all have the servlet in the same project. 
Is it possible at all to make the inputs go to another projects servlet file? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two different projects if you are using same webserver(tomcat)
Lets saa you have two project as below:

http://localhost:8080/FirstProject/

http://localhost:8080/SecondProject/

Please do the following:
In your 1st project: lets assume you have one jsp file at below url:
http://localhost:8080/FirstProject/somePage.jsp

And above jsp is containing below form like:

`<form action='http://localhost:8080/SecondProject/someServlet' >
  <input type='text' name='username'>
</form>`